# Value Error when using add_tokens, 'the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous'

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, tokenize, bert-language-model

I'm trying to improve a basic BERT, pretrained tokenizer model. Im adding new tokens using add_tokens, but running into issues with the built in method.

Namely:

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-64a16974c076> in <cell line: 13>()
     11 # doLowerCase=False
     12 
---> 13 model=train(bert_model_name, model_filename, train_x, train_y, dev_x, dev_y, labels, embedding_size=embedding_size, doLowerCase=doLowerCase)

2 frames
<ipython-input-107-0fe4748e4262> in train(bert_model_name, model_filename, train_x, train_y, dev_x, dev_y, labels, embedding_size, doLowerCase)
      4     bert_model.to(device)
      5 
----> 6     batch_x, batch_y = bert_model.get_batches(train_x, train_y)
      7     dev_batch_x, dev_batch_y = bert_model.get_batches(dev_x, dev_y)
      8 

<ipython-input-105-2f2c405d6463> in get_batches(self, all_x, all_y, batch_size, max_toks)
     46             print(new_tokens)
     47             print("[ BEFORE ] tokenizer vocab size:", len(self.tokenizer))
---> 48             self.tokenizer.add_tokens(new_tokens)
     49             print("[ AFTER ] tokenizer vocab size:", len(self.tokenizer))
     50             batch_x = self.tokenizer(x, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt", max_length=max_toks)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in add_tokens(self, new_tokens, special_tokens)
    977         model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
    978         ```"""
--> 979         if not new_tokens:
    980             return 0
    981 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
````

I'm wondering what I should do to fix it? It doesn't seem like this error should pop up -- after all, many times people would be adding many new tokens (a list of them in `add_tokens`, so why doesn't it work when I do it?)

How do I 'override' this weird value check?

Comment: As the error says, use new_tokens.any(), which will return True if there are any non-null values.

Comment: @Stitt but that would add a boolean -- I need to add the actual list

Comment: please remember i am using a built-in method add_tokens, and I'm trying to add the tokens themselves

Comment: Please post your actual code and not just the error, otherwise we have no chance of helping you.